# Copy Multiple Sheets to over write an existing sheet in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

i am new to VBA and am looking to Copy Sheet1 and Sheet2 to over write an existing sheet, sheet3
so that sheet3 remains upto date, when sheet1 and sheet2 are changed.
Please suggest

Regards
Prasad

Comment: Are you sure that you want to overwrite a sheet? Do you know the meaning of this word? Do you want to move the content of Sheet1 and Sheet2 in the Sheet3? Eventually, starting from Sheet3 last empty row? Or not...

Comment: Hi, Basically want to  over write sheet3

Comment: To overwrite it with both sheets? One after the other?

Comment: Basically Sheet1 & Sheet2, gets updated regularly and have same number of rows and similar data, and i want to keep an updated version of both sheet 1 and 2, merged as one copy in sheet3. so that Sheet3 is always up to date.like a dynamic copy and past. 
so sheet1 rows gets copied first and sheet2 rows after that.

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom of the excel application there is a button to record macro, as shown in image below.

[image]

Click on the button to start recording, it will ask for prompt click `OK`, once you click OK the icon will change as shown in below image,
Now  `Copy Sheet1 and Sheet2 to over write an existing sheet, sheet3`, once finished, Click on stop recording same button (Shown in below image). Now press `Alt`+`F11` button and click on `module` to view the recorded macro.

[image]

To play the macro click on play button as shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: @FunThomas: Good point.   But he may have an idea about what is it about and post here a piece of code which, anyhow is requested...

Comment: Thanks, problem with macro recording is that the number of rows and columns are static and needs a manual intervention when sheet1 gets updated.

Comment: Until you show the sheet 1, sheet 2 and sheet 3 data (what actual you want to replace), it will be difficult to provide the code solution.